# SQL Table based on a pattern

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a Table like:

```
source    target              
jan       feb                               
mar       apr                 
jun                       
feb       aug                                            
apr       jul                                            
oct       dec                     
aug       nov       
dec       may
```

The output (where I want to create a new_target column):

```
source    target    new_target              
jan       feb       aug                        
mar       apr       jul                  
jun                              
feb       aug       nov                                     
apr       jul                                                  
oct       dec       may              
aug       nov       
dec       may
```

The aim is to create `new_target`column based on a logic like - for example, `jan` in source has value `feb` in `target`. This in turn, `feb` in source has a value `aug` in `target`, and so on `aug` has `nov` in `target` column
So the `new_target` column will have 3rd value: i.e (trace followed between source and target `jan->feb->aug->nov`, since `aug` is 3rd value, it is the output in `new_target` column)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a `left join`:

```
select t.*, tnext.target
from t left join
     t tnext
     on t.target = t.next.source
```

Comment: Thanks, just to understand the logic @Gordon Linoff, this would copy `target` column values into `new_target` column whenever `source=target` right. Please correct me if not right

Comment: @omdurg . . . That is what this logic does.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select  m1.source, 
        m1.target, 
        m2.target as new_target
from mytable m1
left join mytable m2 on 
  m1.target = m2.source
```

The `left join` will maintain all rows from the original table, while adding values to the `new_target` column if there is a match.